# PHP for loop with exception rules

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am searching for a php for loop, which should output
22,23,24, 32,33,34, and so on 92,93,94 and all following like 102,103,104,122,123 until 902,903,904,992,993,9949, but not or 12,13,14... 112,13,114 ...912,913,914.

my code:

```
for ($a = 22; $a <= 1000; $a+=10) {
    $b = $a  + 1;
    $c = $a  + 2;   
    echo "$a <br>";
    echo "$b <br>";
    echo "$c <br>";
}
```

I need here an exception, because 112,123 and 124 and so on until 912,913,914 shouldn't be echoed.
All results should be stored in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found all parts do finish [kwestgrounds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33660904/3751899) with my exceptions.

```
$delete = array_merge(range (112, 912, 100), range (113, 913, 100),range (114, 914, 100));
$data = array();
for ($a = 2; $a < 100; $a++) {
  for ($b = 2; $b <= 4; $b++) {       
    $c = ($a * 10) + $b;
{
    if (in_array($c, $delete)) continue;
}         
    $data[] = $c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
$data = array();
for ($a = 2; $a < 10; $a++) {
  for ($b = 2; $b <= 4; $b++) {
    $c = ($a * 10) + $b;
    $data[] = $c;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't need the results 112,113,114,212,213,214 and so on until 912,913,914.

Comment: But I need the results 102,103,104,122,123,124, etc. 192,193,194,... untl 992,993,994. Now is 94  the last one. not 112,113,114 ... and so on until 912,913,914.

Comment: @Grischa can you take what kwestground has done and expand it?